# Why is the latest possible version not being installed in CI with caret versioning

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, yarnpkg

I have some nested dependencies that use caret versioning e.g. `"lodash" :"^4.2.0"`.

Why is it that when I install packages from a fresh clone, I don't get the latest version that supports that versioning? Currently that would be - `4.17.21`. I could understand if my other packages need a lower version of lodash but they also have something similar with caret versions.

For some reason `4.17.20` is being installed by yarn. Something is telling my yarn lockfile to resolve to `4.17.20`. The only way I can get around this is to use resolutions in my `package.json` however this is occurring for many packages and I don't want to do this if possible. Is there something I'm missing that is causing versions to be resolved in the lockfile?

Comment: I would assume some other package requires `4.17.20` as the max allowed version so yarn will install this specific version to confront both requirements instead of installing two separate versions. (I don't use yarn, but it works this way in NPM, so I assume it the same in yarn as well.)

Comment: The other packages have the same requirement. I mentioned in the question about this. That would makes sense if that was the case.

Comment: Do you check all transitive dependencies as well or leaf dependencies only? If the first then I have no idea.